# Convert m/d format dates

Tags: c#, date

We are getting some weird date that need to be parsed in right format using c#.

We are getting like this..

9/3 2332 need to format in to 09/03/2016 23:32 (year should be current year)

How i can accomplished this using parse date functions.

Comment: where's the code?

Comment: `DateTime.ParseExact(@"9/3 2332", @"M/d Hm", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)` worked for me, assuming the hours and minutes are not zero-padded, if they are then use `@"M/d HHmm"` format instead. I downvoted because despite my "answer" this is not a "write my code for me" service. This is so trivial I don't see a reason not to give a quick answer, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of playing with [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var x = DateTime.ParseExact("9/3 2332", "d/M HHmm", null);
```